# How to manage size of tkz points?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-collection

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\tkzInit[xmax=25,ymax=25]

\tkzDefPoint(0,0){C}

\tkzDefPoint(0,2){B}

\tkzDefPoint(0,4){A}

\tkzDefPoint(4,0){F}

\tkzDefPoint(4,2){E}

\tkzDefPoint(4,4){D}

\tkzDrawPoints[color=black,shape=circle,fill=black](C, B, A, D, E, F)

\tkzLabelPoint[left](C){$C$}

\tkzLabelPoint[left](B){$B$}

\tkzLabelPoint[left](A){$A$}

\tkzLabelPoint[right](D){$D$}

\tkzLabelPoint[right](E){$E$}

\tkzLabelPoint[right](F){$F$}



\tkzDrawSegments(A,D A,E A,F)
\tkzDrawSegments(B,D B,E B,F)
\tkzDrawSegments(C,D C,E C,F)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Question:  How can i increase and decrese the size of tkz points?

Comment: I don't know why but I cannot compile your example. Does it work for you? Btw you could display your commands as code with an identation of four spaces.

Comment: Do not confuse "TikZ points" and "tkz points"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`size=<number>`, giving a size in points, or `size=<length>` (e.g. `size=5mm`). Add to the `\tkzDrawPoints` options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\tkzInit[xmax=25,ymax=25]

\tkzDefPoint(0,0){C}
\tkzDefPoint(0,2){B}
\tkzDefPoint(0,4){A}
\tkzDefPoint(4,0){F}
\tkzDefPoint(4,2){E}
\tkzDefPoint(4,4){D}

\tkzDrawPoints[color=black,shape=circle,fill=black,size=15](C, B, A, D, E, F)

\tkzLabelPoints[left](A,B,C)
\tkzLabelPoints[right](D,E,F)

\tkzDrawSegments(A,D A,E A,F)
\tkzDrawSegments(B,D B,E B,F)
\tkzDrawSegments(C,D C,E C,F)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot........... one more question how to put directions on edges of graph?

Comment: @snehal Can you try adding all your requirements at once, so that I don't have to redo my answer? Try e.g. `\tkzDrawSegments[-stealth,shorten >=3pt](A,D A,E A,F)`.